# How do I access windows items(?) from inside a VB.net program

Tags: windows, vb.net

I am not really sure how to ask this question. I have been teaching myself vb for about 3 months. The book I am using is pretty good about explaining things and what I can't figure out I can find different examples on the web. I can't find out how to access windows control panels from my app. For example if I type firewall.cpl at the run line it will launch the windows firewall. How do I launch that from my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) to execute other programs.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path to\firewall.cpl")
```

Comment: Thanks now I know what I am looking for I can do A little research.